# Update table using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Foo` table with the following attributes:

```
FooID (PK) | Bar | Price
```

Given that a sample record set is:

```
1 | 332 | 10
2 | 332 | 10
3 | 333 | 5
4 | 334 | 30
4 | 334 | 30
4 | 334 | 30
```

I want the output of the query to be

```
1 | 332 | 5
2 | 332 | 5
3 | 333 | 5
4 | 334 | 10
4 | 334 | 10
4 | 334 | 10
```

In other words, the `Price` column, should be the result of: `Price/N` where N is the number of times that the given `Bar` exists in the record set.

I have managed to count the number of `Bars` that exist using:

```
  select Bar, count(*) as BarCount from Foo GROUP BY Bar
```

However, I have no clue how I am going to apply this to the division of the `Price`.

Thanks!

Comment: Personally I wouldn't store values like this in the database. The main reason being that otherwise you need to update every row with that ID  (`bar`) every time a row in inserted, deleted, or updated. That is most likely going to require triggers. You would most likely be better off with using a `VIEW`.

Comment: And what happens when a given bar has different prices? Which price do you use in your math? Do you assume that all prices are the same for a given bar? Is that a **safe** assumption?

Answer (score 4):

You can use window functions and division:

```
select fooid, bar, 
       price / count(*) over (partition by bar) as new_price
from t;
```

### Demo

Note that SQL Server does integer division.  So if `price` is an integer, you might get a more accurate result with:

```
select fooid, bar, 
       price * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by bar) as new_price
from t;
```

EDIT:

The title says "update", but the question only mentions getting results.  If you want an update use an updatable CTE or subquery:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, 
             price / count(*) over (partition by bar) as new_price
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set new_price = price
    where price <> new_price;
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer here +1, and I would have given it myself, expect that Gordon is actually an AI program created by Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey StackOverflow . . . If you ever want to create such an AI program, I'd be delighted to help.

Comment: Agreed with @TimBiegeleisen!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This solution was perfect! The edit was also relevant, because as you mentioned, I forgot to add the update part on the question (sorry about that)!

Comment: Very funny discussion ! Personnaly, I really considered Gordon being an AI, especially last month when I started following the sql tag... Thanks for schooling us Gordon !

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CTE which finds the counts for each `Bar` group, and then join to it to find the quotients:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Bar, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Bar
)

SELECT t1.FooID, t1.Bar,
   1.0 * t1.Price / t2.cnt AS NewPrice
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Bar = t2.Bar
ORDER BY
    t1.Bar, t1.FooID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Gordon's answer is probably the fastest, because it finds the counts and computes the quotients in one single pass over the entire table.  The answer I gave requires an additional subquery and join.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated subquery to compute the divider :

> ```
> WITH myTable AS (
>     SELECT 1 AS FooID, 332 AS Bar, 10 AS Price UNION ALL
>     SELECT 2, 332, 10 UNION ALL
>     SELECT 3, 333, 5  UNION ALL
>     SELECT 4, 334, 30 UNION ALL
>     SELECT 4, 334, 30 UNION ALL
>     SELECT 4, 334, 30
> )    
> SELECT 
>     t.fooid,
>     t.bar,
>     t.price / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE bar = t.bar)
> FROM myTable t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> fooid | bar | (No column name)
> ----: | --: | ---------------:
>     1 | 332 |                5
>     2 | 332 |                5
>     3 | 333 |                5
>     4 | 334 |               10
>     4 | 334 |               10
>     4 | 334 |               10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9f79a28fe1cf8117f4085977f91cbad)*